# Empty option as default select when ngoptions data is bound asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have the ngoptions array bound asynchronously inside my controller. When I create a select with it, there is an empty option being created. How do I avoid?

```
<select  data-ng-model="order.employee" ng-options="employee._id as employee.name for
    employee in employeess"> </select>
```

My controller code

```
Employees.query(function(employees){
    $scope.employees = employees
});
```

How do I avoid empty select being created? I tried ng-init but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: I've answered your question, please have a look at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

(1) You can create blank option. This will be selected by default.

```
$scope.order.employee = -1

<select  data-ng-model="order.employee" ng-options="employee._id as employee.name for
    employee in employeess"> 
   <option value="-1">--Select--<option>
</select>
```

(2) You can select first option

```
Employees.query(function(employees){
    $scope.employees = employees
    $scope.order.employee = employees.length ? employee[0]._id : -1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't initialized your model.
You have to set a default value for your ng-model="order.employee" in your controller.
Like:

```
$scope.order.employee = -1
```

and your select should have this structure:

```
<select  data-ng-model="order.employee" ng-options="employee._id as employee.name for
    employee in employeess"> 
   <option value="-1">Click to Select<option>
</select>
```